# How do I vmtouch a directory (not the files it contains)?

Tags: linux, directory, virtual-memory

The [vmtouch(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vmtouch) tool allows locking a file or files in memory. It has recursive mode, but the directories are used just for discovering files and are not locked themselves.

How do I lock a directory in memory, so that readdir be always fast until I unlock it?

Answer (score 4):

`vmtouch` is definitely NOT going to manage this. `vmtouch` does `open(2)` & `mmap(2)` on the files you instruct it to.

Even if you get the kernel to cache `readdir(2)`, it's still a linear operation, and [still hits disk in many cases](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~porter/pubs/sosp15-final.pdf):

> In the current VFS readdir operation, the low-level
>   file system is always called, even if the entire directory is in
>   cache.

**(2017/08/07 18:40 UTC followup):**

`ls -l` does a lot more than just `readdir`. `readdir(2)` is obsolete anyway, `readdir(3)` is a wrapper for `(f)stat` on the directory & `getdents` on the directory. The `-l` option of `ls` also causes an `lstat` on every entry in it.

`getdents` in itself is just a wrapper to whatever a given filesystem provides for the `.iterate_shared` & `.iterate` pointers on directory file struct's operations. In the case of `ext4`, this winds up down in `ext4_readdir`.

Some filesystems do implement caching at that layer (NFS is a very clear example), but others might hit disk still.

For the root of your original question, you could write some daemon that repeatedly keeps running `getdents` on a given directory, but there's no way to pin those dentry items in the kernel cache otherwise, and it's possible that the kernel completely ignores that cache from a separate thread (depends on the filesystem).

Focusing on `ext4` for a moment, if the filesystem has the `dir_index` feature, you can do  `chattr +I dir` on a directory to mark a directory as being htree-indexed (very small directories use that cache as well if the filesystem feature is set)

Comment: Typically second, hot `ls -l` is much faster than the first. I want pin this "hotness" until I release it, not to wear out after time passes or other content gets accessed. For example, pressing Tab twice makes bash wait for 6 seconds before presenting `Display all 9454 possibilities?` the first time, but not second time. How to I tell system not to forget this state of fast tab completion?

Comment: My response was too long for a comment, so I edited it in.

Comment: If you want to instruct the system to keep file metadata in cache for longer, you might want to look into lowering `vm.vfs_cache_pressure` so that it prefers to keep metadata over file content.